# Firebase Query From Multiple Nested Child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have below firebase database structure. I an trying to query `m_no` which is nested under a dynamically created arraylist

[image]

below is the code i have tried but it is not working.Any idea how to query this?

```
 mReferenceBooks=mDataBase.getReference("book").child("dMoble");

 mReferenceBooks.orderByChild("m_no").equalTo(emailID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  }
```

Comment: If you want to do so, you need to use `for`.

Comment: how can i use a for here?

Comment: for better performance query, Peter Haddad's answer is the best to follow

Comment: do you want to know drivers data based on mobile number?

Comment: yes based on mobile no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query wont work because above the `dMoble`, you have the random id. Therefore you need to access that `id` and add it as a `child()` to be able to query:

```
mReferenceBooks=mDataBase.getReference("book").child("-Ly3FuE6GF-oExG2puhj").child("dMoble");
```

Comment: Ly3FuE6GF-oExG2puhj is actually push key

Comment: yes you need to have that value, to do this query.. since you have to traverse from the top node to the `dMoble`

Comment: When saving the push do: `String pushKey = ref.push().getKey()` this will store the key in a variable which you can use

Comment: can it be accessible using getkey or anyother method

Comment: When saving the push do: String pushKey = ref.push().getKey() this will store the key in a variable which you can use

Comment: currently I am saving by this DatabaseReference newBid=mDatabase.push(); adding mDatabase.push().getkey() giving error

Comment: under that line then do `String key = mDatabase.push().getKey()`

Comment: I am inserting from one app and need to retreive data in another app. then will it work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205581/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-mithu).